# SUM when using INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get the SUM when using INDEX/MATCH but I keep failing.
I want to get the SUM of each month. How do I do this with INDEX MATCH?

I tried with formula below but I keep getting the total and I want the total per month.

```
SUM.IF(Tabel 1::E3:E21;INDEX(Tabel 1::E3:E21;MATCH(A4;Tabel 1::A3:A21;0)))
```

[image]

I want the result in the table below.

[image]

Comment: What value are you putting in the first criterion of the match?, what is in A4?

Comment: What version of Excel is that in the image and what regional language is it?

Comment: I'm using Numbers for Apple but it works the same as Excel. If I get the formula in excel and in english I can translate it to Numbers in Dutch. I added some details to my post to make it clear what I want.

Comment: Get rid of the INDEX/MATCH: in EXCEL it would be `=SUMIF(Table1!A:A,B3,Table1!E:E)`

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above. I would use sumif(s). Not index match.

Put in B3 Tabel 2

```
=SUMIFS(tabel1!E:E,tabel1!A:A,tabel2!A3)
```

or

```
=SUMIF(tabel1!A:A,tabel2!A3,tabel1!E:E)
```